# Central git repo on server, push and pull from it

Tags: git, clone, push, pull

This could very well be a duplicate question, but I just can't find a satisfying answer to my question.
The situation is this, I've got a webserver which I can talk to over ssh and it has git installed.
There is a folder on it that represends a website. Previously, everyone would just work on the server at the same time (via FTP) or download a copy to there machine, work on it there, and FTP it back.

What I want now, is make that folder a git repo, which people can clone to there local machine. Work on it, and push the changes back to the server.

How do I do this? I've tried just creating a repo on the server. I can clone this repo, but can't push anything to it. I've read some things about a bare git repo, but it seems to me this doesn't work for my problem, because I want the repo on the server to be the actual website folder and files.

I really hope someone can help, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server. This document is widely available and very comprehensive, covering everything about setting up a git server.

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest to separate the git repository from the deployment directory.

Pushing to the server the repository and deploying in production a new version of your sites **must** obey to different workflow. In fact you should push to the git repository many times per day...

Given that you already have ssh access, you should simply

- use a bare repository, in the standard way you found
- build a one line deployment script based on scp or rsync (of course you should commit this script) and execute this script from one of the development computers

**EDIT :**

here's an example of a one line deployement script for a web site :

```
rsync -avz --del --stats --exclude="deploy.sh" /path/Chrall/web/* someid@someweb.org:/var/www/canop/chrall
```

And I use usually slightly more complex (4 or 5 lines and a config) scripts in real projects (ref [one of my github repositories](https://github.com/Canop/braldop/tree/master/scripts)).

Comment: I see what you mean. But how would I do the second step? "build a one..."?

Comment: I edited with a very simple example. In most of my projects I have scripts enabling the deployement using rsync from my test repository (on my dev computer) to the production servers.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple howto for preparing git deployment of web:**

- Prepare list of files, which **should not be shared** - temp and data directories - into file `.gitignore` in directory on web server, which should begin to be shared:

  ```
  cd /var/www/mydomain.org/
  echo temp >> .gitignore
  echo data >> .gitignore
  ```
- Initiate git repository in this directory:

  ```
  git init
  git add -A
  git commit -m "Init"
  ```
- Allow pushing into this repository, though it is not bare repository:

  ```
  git config receive.denycurrentbranch false
  ```
- Add hook to set working tree to current version when new version is pushed - this script will be started after pushing:

  ```
  echo '#!/bin/sh'        >  .git/hooks/post-receive
  echo 'git checkout -f'  >> .git/hooks/post-receive
  echo 'git reset --hard' >> .git/hooks/post-receive
  chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
  ```

Now should be server prepared, now you can clone repository to client and push back normally.